# Grabar un archivo de audio en Android (Ionic Angular Capacitor)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

Buenas noches a todos,

Llevo bastante con este problema y necesito orientación, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, muy probablemente si, y es por ello que recurro a este recurso.

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación movil en base a Ionic 6, Angular y Capacitor y actualmente enfrento el siguiente problema:

Necesito grabar un archivo de audio en un dispositivo Android, para lo cual utilizo el plugin "Media" que uso de la siguiente manera, basándome en la [documentación oficial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media).

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
```

Para lograr mi objetivo he desarrollado 3 funciones básicas:

Esta función es llamada al presionar un botón en la vista:

```html
  record(){
    this.isRecording?this.stopRecord():this.startRecord()
    this.isRecording = !this.isRecording
  }
```

Y las funciones que manejan la grabación  son las que siguen:

```html
startRecord(){
    this.fireAuth.fireauth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        let now = new Date();

        console.log('Grabando')
        this.newFile = this.media.create('file:///sdcard//Download/'+user.uid+'-'+this.formatDate(now)+'.mp3');
        this.newFile.startRecord();

      }else{
        console.log('USUARIO NO AUTENTICADO')
      }
    })
  }
  
stopRecord(){
    console.log('Grabacion terminada')

    this.newFile.stopRecord();
    this.newFile.release();
}
```

Con esto lo que consigo es basicamente un montón de errores en la consola de Android Studio:

**Al llamar startRecord()**

```html
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: INVALID, service: Media, action: create, actionArgs: ["28dcbcf9-4453-bb1b-8faf-74c13e4ec29c","file:\/\/\/sdcard\/\/Download\/xZpEzJ12P2dblXAxG7Wpo2J2xpf2-20210604010355.mp3"]
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/tab1-tab1-module.js - Line 189 - Msg: Grabando
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: INVALID, service: Media, action: startRecordingAudio, actionArgs: ["28dcbcf9-4453-bb1b-8faf-74c13e4ec29c","file:\/\/\/sdcard\/\/Download\/xZpEzJ12P2dblXAxG7Wpo2J2xpf2-20210604010355.mp3"]
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1622783035225.3gp: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:289)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:152)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:1091)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioPlayer.startRecording(AudioPlayer.java:161)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.startRecordingAudio(AudioHandler.java:287)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.promptForRecord(AudioHandler.java:543)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:118)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:51)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        ... 15 more
```

**Al llamar stopRecord()**

```html
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: INVALID, service: Media, action: stopRecordingAudio, actionArgs: ["28dcbcf9-4453-bb1b-8faf-74c13e4ec29c"]
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/tab1-tab1-module.js - Line 199 - Msg: Grabacion terminada
E/AudioPlayer: /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1622783035225.3gp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording-1622783035225.3gp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioPlayer.moveFile(AudioPlayer.java:216)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioPlayer.stopRecording(AudioPlayer.java:311)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.stopRecordingAudio(AudioHandler.java:298)
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:107)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:51)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160) 
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioPlayer.moveFile(AudioPlayer.java:216) 
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioPlayer.stopRecording(AudioPlayer.java:311) 
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.stopRecordingAudio(AudioHandler.java:298) 
        at org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:121) 
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98) 
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132) 
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:107) 
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:51) 
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: INVALID, service: Media, action: release, actionArgs: ["28dcbcf9-4453-bb1b-8faf-74c13e4ec29c"]
```

Mencionar además que a partir de estas funciones si que se crea un archivo de audio en el dispositivo, pero tiene 0 bytes y no puede ser abierto (adjunto algunos ejemplos de ellos):

[image: archivos generados cada vez que se llama a estas funciones]

He probado todas las soluciones [que ofrecen en este enlace del foro de ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/mediaplugin-does-not-save-audio-recording-into-file-ionic-native/91868/16), todas han dado resultados similares...sospecho que "callbackId: INVALID" tiene que ver en todo esto pero no encuentro forma de enfrentar esto por mi cuenta, gracias a quienes se tomen el tiempo de responder, esto me está complicando mucho la vida en este momento.